# MarkerClusterer zooming issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm using the latest version of MarkerClusterer with Google Maps API v3 and I think I've found a bug!

My google map minZoom is set to 1. Zooming from level 1 down to any level and back up to 1 is just fine. The bug is seen when I try to zoom out from level 1 to level 0.

When I click to zoom out from level 1 to level 0, the gMap UI doesn't allow the zoom, as intended, but all my markerClusters disappear, they re-appear when I go down to zoom level 2 and come back to level 1.

I've posted this on the Google Group page for Google Maps API v3, but no response so far (been over a week as of today).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: markerClusterer is not a part of the Maps-Javascript-API, you should report the bug at https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/entry

Comment: Thanks, I'll post a comment there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more a bug in the Maps-API than a bug in markerClusterer, but you can fix it in [markerClusterer.js](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js)

I'm not sure where you click on when you(try to) set the zoom to 0(the issue for me doesn't occur when I use the zoom-control), but it happens when I set the zoom using `map.setZoom(0)`

The issue: the API reports a zoom of 0, but this is incorrect, because the zoom will be set to 1(the minZoom).

**Fix:**
Replace this part of marcerclusterer.js:

```
// Add the map event listeners
  var that = this;
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = that.map_.getZoom();

    if (that.prevZoom_ != zoom) {
      that.prevZoom_ = zoom;
      that.resetViewport();
    }
  });
```

...with that:

```
  // Add the map event listeners
  var that = this;
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = that.map_.getZoom(),
        minZoom=that.map_.minZoom||0,
        maxZoom=Math.min(that.map_.maxZoom||100,
                         that.map_.mapTypes[that.map_.getMapTypeId()].maxZoom);
        zoom=Math.min(Math.max(zoom,minZoom),maxZoom);

    if (that.prevZoom_ != zoom) {
      that.prevZoom_ = zoom;
      that.resetViewport();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hey Dr Molle, your solution works! But due to some other bugs in markerClusterer I had to upgrade to markerclustererPlus. I am using v2.0.9 [link](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/src/markerclusterer.js) and the same bug is present there. I tried to incorporate your solution in markerclustererPlus but was unsuccessful. Could you look at this and let me know how to fix the bug here? [(line 723)](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/src/markerclusterer.js)

Comment: I was pointing to google maps v3.5, just updated that and it fixed the problem with markerClustererPlus! Thanks for your help :)